# How to update multiple columns of a single row in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with only one row for the moment and I want to update some column of that row.
the insert method is executed correctly while, update returns an id = 0 and printing the username is always the previous one and is not updated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME1+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, WON INT, DRAW INT, LOST INT, CELLSNUMBER INT,RESULT INT)");        
}
public boolean addUserInformation(String name, int w, int l, int d, boolean firstTime){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(USERNAME, name);
        values.put(WIN, w);
        values.put(LOST, l);
        values.put(DRAW, d);

        long id = 0;
        if(firstTime == true ) {
            id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, values);
        }
        if(firstTime == false){
            id=db.update(TABLE_NAME1, values, "USERNAME = ? and WON = ? and DRAW = ?  and LOST = ?",new String[] {
                    name,
                    String.valueOf(w),
                    String.valueOf(d),
                    String.valueOf(l)
            });
        }
        if(id == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to update the row with `USERNAME = name` with the values `w, d, l`.
The 3d argument of the [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method is the `WHERE` clause and in it you should have only:

```
USERNAME = ?
```

so do it like this:

```
id = db.update(TABLE_NAME1, values, "USERNAME = ?", new String[] {name});
```

The values `w, d, l` need not be inside the `WHERE` clause. They are saved in the variable `values` and will update the row in the table.